# Why does the "offline for maintenance" page have many color themes?

Tags: discussion

Few moments ago I landed on this remarkable page:

[image: Offline for maintenance]

After [few Google](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2371806) searches, I understood that those errors are real and are  old version of Microsoft's C compiler runtime error messages (available on [this list](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/c_errors_-msc-.html)).

That's really cool, but why do we have **6** different color themes? Is there a reason behind that?

**Note**: There's no random selection, the themes are shown in the **same** page, all at once.

Comment: To cater to color-blind people, of course. At least one image in the set must be legible regardless of one's affectation.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Can't tell if that's meant to be tongue-in-cheek...

Comment: @Bolt, tell me about it. Me neither.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi What about blind$ people? Shouldn't we have braille system for that page?

Comment: @Maroun, screen readers and braille "screens" may not be able to OCR the images, but they will render the *SO is currently offline for maintenance* sentence just fine.

Comment: .. So there's no real reason for why we have 6 themes.

Comment: Why does there have to be a reason?

Comment: @Cerbrus There doesn't. I'll accept the "**there's no reason.**" answer.

Comment: It is a screenshot of an ancient version of gedit (a Unix text editor) displaying the content of a MS-Dos exe file.  Split-screen by the looks of it, the cursor is on the top 'window'.  There were no color schemes back then, no D/A converters that were fast enough so the monitor interface was digital.  Using only 4 bits, 1 each for red, green and blue and an intensity bit so you got only [16 hard-baked colors](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/CGA-NTSC-colors.png/330px-CGA-NTSC-colors.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer is: There's no reason.

Answer (score 4):

> Variation is the spice of life

Why should SO have a *single* image? A little variation is fun.

Of course I'm no SE employee, but I bet that's the reason: *"Why not?"*

Comment: That's all in the same page.

Comment: Do you still have an link to the error page?

Comment: No. I don't think it's a bug. I always get **6** images in the same page.

Comment: Why should it be a bug? why wouldn't it be by design?

Comment: @Maroun Maroun: Who said anything about it being a bug?

Comment: @Cerbrus: I don't think the offline-for-maintenance page has a dedicated URL...

Comment: I'n not sure why Maroun mentioned "bug", even. @BoltClock: that's a shame, but as I remember, it's been like this for a long time.

Comment: @BoltClock Because OP said *single* page. I thought he's thinking we have only one image in the page, which is random one. But it's not the case, we're having 6 images in the same page, which is why I clarified it's not a bug that we have more and not random one.

Comment: @BoltClock Your edit changed the whole meaning of the post ;) but maybe made it more accurate.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: He didn't. The edit is fine.

Comment: @Cerbrus *why in single error page* was confusing. It *is* in a single page.